# Why I cannot map data?

Tags: reactjs, charts

I'm trying to map "historicData" and put them in the labels of chart but it gives me error,"u cannot map the undefined".
So,Error is historicData is undefined .When I console.log(historicData),there is an array data.
This is my Code.

https://github.com/Saithiha24/React-Crypto-Beast/blob/master/src/Components/CoinInfo.js

I try to solve this for 2 days still can't find the answer. Please help me.

Comment: Your Link gives `{"error":"Not Found"}`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that historicData is initially undefined, and while waiting for the async call to complete and give historicData a value, you get the error. I suggest you change this

```
const [historicData, setHistoricData] = useState();
```

to this

```
const [historicData, setHistoricData] = useState([]);
```

so historicData is originally an empty array instead of undefined. You can also change the definition of data likes this

```
const data = {
labels: historicData ? historicData.map((coin) => {
//your code
}) : []}
```

so that if historicData is undefined, you don't try to map, just assign an empty array to labels.